# Current user filter

Tags: webforms

I have a web form, and I want to filter records by current user from views module, when I select filter "submitted by" and use equal to [current-user:uid], I don't get any results, can someone help me, I don't realize what I'm doing wrong. Thank you[image]

Comment: This should be a contextual filter of the current user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin ! It works perfect

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to not use a query filter for the user id, but to use a contextual filter on the current user instead. This will grab the current users ID as a dynamic filter in a View.